# Fortran 90 data statement does not overwrite data

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to initialize an array using `DATA` statement in Fortran 90. The code is following:

```
PROGRAM dt_state
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: a(4), b(2:2), c(10)

DATA a/4*0/
WRITE (6,*) a(:)    

DATA a/4,3,2,1/
WRITE (6,*) a(:)
END PROGRAM dt_state
```

I expected that results on the screen will be `0  0  0  0` and `4 3 2 1`. However, what I got is `0 0 0 0` and `0 0 0 0`. It means `DATA` statement does not overwrite the values of `a`, does it?

Comment: does this really compile without even a warning?

Comment: Yes, in all my compilers.

Comment: @george I recognized that in the variable declaration, there is a mistake of typing, `b(2:2)`, which is nonsense (should be `b(2,2)` ). However, it is not a bug and compiling does not yield any warning

Comment: i was expecting the redundant data statement to throw a warning. not the first thing ive been wrong about...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable can appear in a DATA statement only once. The DATA statement is for initialization, which is done only once at program start.

In executable code use assignment to set array values

```
a = (/ 4, 3, 2, 1 /)
```

(in Fortran 90)

or

```
a = [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

(in Fortran 2003).

It is better to use this syntax also for initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not standard-compliant.  That is: from F2008 5.2.3:

> A variable, or part of a variable, shall not be explicitly initialized more than once in a program.

The `DATA` statement (is one thing that) performs such explicit initialization (5.4.7.1), and so in particular two cannot appear for the same variable.

For your second "initialization", use assignment.  [As given by @VladimirF who is a faster typist than I.]  Further, while one can put a `DATA` statement with executable statements, as in this case, the standard goes as far as making that obsolescent (B.2.5):

> The ability to position DATA statements amongst executable statements is very rarely used, unnecessary, and a potential source of error.

As the code is non-standard, and the error is not one the compiler is required to detect, the compiler is free to whatever it likes with the code.  I thought it would be interesting to see what we do see with a small selection:

- One refused to compile (and also pointed out the obsolesence);
- Two quietly went ahead, using the first initialization;
- One used the second initialization, warning.

Of course, one wouldn't want to rely on any of these behaviours, even if it was a desired one.

Comment: Indeed, I first had to find whether this position of DATA is even allowed.

Comment: @francescalus: By the way, you mentioned the source F2008 5.2.3 and B.2.5 Can you please tell me what are they? Thank you

Comment: @hoangtran References to the (draft) Fortran 2008 standard: http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf.  Sorry, I should have been clearer.